# Problemas em relacionar o colisor com navmesh Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, detecção-de-colisão

Pessoal sou iniciante em relação a Unity e c#, e como geralmente acontece, estou com um problema e não sei resolver.
Estou tentando relacionar o collider com o navmesh na unity, onde assim que o Agent (NPC) colidir com a box collider do Local, imprima uma mensagem de "Colidiu" (eu vou fazer mais coisas alem de imprimir mensagem, mas primeiro quero fazer a colisão acontecer).
[Então eu fiz esse script básico, onde na minha concepção eu estou dizendo que assim que assim que o objeto que contenha esse script, colida com a tag "Local", imprima a mensagem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i14Su.png)

[NA Unity, eu adicionei o script no local, com a box collider certinha.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTP16.jpg)

[Só que mesmo acontecendo a colisão visualmente, ela em si não acontece.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZMVv.jpg)

Queria saber onde estou errando, se alguem puder me ajudar, agradeço demais..

Answer (score -2):

Yago, os possiveis problemas que pode ocasionar são listados abaixo:

1. Nenhum dos objetos que vão colidir tem collider ou um tem e outro não.
2. Nenhum dos objetos que vão colidir tem Rigidbody.Pelo menos um tem que ter.
3. Como você está utilizando OnTriggerEnter um dos dois colliders tem que está marcado a opção 'is Trigger'.
4. Como você está utilizando CompareTag("nomeDeAlgo"), verifique se a tag está atribuida no objeto(personagem) que vai colidir com seu collider(local). E também se o nome está igual o que está escrito no seu CompareTag("Verifique aqui") porque o as vezes pode está com letra maiuscula e na sua tag que você criou não e a escrita está diferente.

Depois dessa todos verificações tente ver o que seu OnTriggerEnter(**Collider** other) está trazendo.
ex:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.transform.name); // isso qualquer coisa que colidir você saber e terá a confirmação que essa parte está certa e você pode partir para verificação com if.
    }
```